# ZipForge and invalid archives

Tags: delphi, testing, compression, zip

I have [ZipForge for Delphi XE2](http://www.componentace.com/download/download.php?editionid=12) & Delphi XE2.

I try to test any invalid zip archives (e.g. not fully downloaded) like in their demo:

```
procedure TfmMain.bnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Archiver do
  begin
    FileName := 'c:\2.zip';
    OpenArchive;
    try
      TestFiles('*.*');
    except
      MessageDlg('Errors occurred in the archive file', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
    end;
    CloseArchive;
  end;
end;
```

But my exception doesn't fire; ZipForge's dialog fires instead of mine.

I tried [Abbrevia Component](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/) but it even can't recognize if an archive is invalid...

Please help me to make my exception working (not ZipForge's one) or suggest me a better component for zip files with a test feature. Thanks!

Comment: How does the built in XE2 ZIP class handle it

Comment: I can't see a source :( There is nothing to do (or almost nothing) with that component, maybe there is something better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that you can modify ZIP files, e.g. by truncating them somewhat, the ZIP file will still be valid. With my test file, I removed the final 5000 bytes and it was reported as valid. I extracted it successfully using my ZIP program. Of course the extracted contents were incorrect and not the original contents. Perhaps this is what was happening for you. Maybe your attempts to corrupt your ZIP file were not in fact making it into an invalid ZIP file.

Delphi XE2 comes with a built in ZIP component that worked well in my simple test and successfully detected an invalid file, once I had truncated the file enough to make it truly corrupt.

I used the [`IsValid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.IsValid) method to check validity. Here is my very simple test program.

```
program ZipTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Zip;

procedure Main;
const
  ZipArchive = 'C:\desktop\test.zip';
var
  ZipFile: TZipFile;
  FileName: string;
begin
  ZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    if ZipFile.IsValid(ZipArchive) then begin
      ZipFile.Open(ZipArchive, zmRead);
      for FileName in ZipFile.FileNames do begin
        Writeln(FileName);
      end;
    end else begin
      Writeln(ZipArchive + ' not valid');
    end;
  finally
    ZipFile.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an invalid ZIP file, it is most likely that the call to `OpenArchive` will fail. As long as your execption handling doesn't cover that case, you will get the result you describe.

Update: The suggested way to catch exceptions during `TestFiles` or any other method is to connect an `OnProcessFileFailure` event handler.

Comment: I didn't want to write/edit a code much myself. 2 components above are not good enough, they can't handle invalid archives.

Comment: I expect they can handle them fine. Problem most likely in your code.

Comment: Apparently, according to the docs I found (.net admittedly), if you don't specify `OnProcessFileFailure` then an exception is raised.

Comment: @David, as often the docs don't match the source. The source says, when you don't specify the event, an internal dialog is shown - unless you switched of the DIALOGS compiler option leading to no dialog but no exception either.

Comment: @Uwe Probably because I was reading .net docs and Delphi code is different. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @David, the Delphi doc says the same. I guess the described behaviour had been valid some time ago, but no one updated the docs when they changed it.